# mysql - sql query multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database in 2 versions: 25-7-2015 let's call it **db1** and 5-8-2015 let's call it **db2**.

I am running the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.couponid, c.branchid, c.chainid
FROM `users_roles` a,
`field_data_field_ypefthinos` b,
`custom_redemptions` c,
`field_data_field_chain_manager` e,
`field_data_field_node_tax_inception` f,
`field_data_field_brand_manager` j,
`field_data_field_brand_node_ref` k,
`field_data_field_product_ref` i,
`field_data_field_company_manager` z,
`field_data_field_brand_company` t
WHERE
(a.rid = 4
AND a.uid = 1
AND b.field_ypefthinos_uid = a.uid
AND b.entity_id = c.branchid)
```

on db1 I get results normally without errors, on db2 I get no results without any error. I tried some debugging by removing unused tables and narrowed it down to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.couponid, c.branchid, c.chainid
FROM `users_roles` a,
`field_data_field_ypefthinos` b,
`custom_redemptions` c,
`field_data_field_chain_manager` e,
`field_data_field_node_tax_inception` f,
`field_data_field_brand_company` t
WHERE
(a.rid = 4
AND a.uid = 1
AND b.field_ypefthinos_uid = a.uid
AND b.entity_id = c.branchid)
```

Which prints results normally on db2 as it would with query1 on db1.

Nothing was changed between the 2 databases, the data in the tables a,b,c haven't been changed but the when I remove unused tables I get the result I want but not all the unused tables so it's not that.

My problem however is the query is dynamic and at some point I need all included tables.

So what's the problem?

Comment: Why are you using other tables which are not at all joined properly?

Comment: What do you mean? Everything is joined properly, it used to work fine 10 days ago

Comment: I presume you have the same structure, but different datasets. By any chance, is any of the tables `field_data_field_brand_manager`, `field_data_field_brand_node_ref`, `field_data_field_product_ref` or `field_data_field_company_manager` empty ?

Comment: Yep the problem between then and now is some tables are now empty but they're not used so the query should't be affected, is there any work-around to ignore empty tables incase they're not used?

Comment: Unless you can edit the query to ignore the tables, or load dummy data, there is no way to force the natural cartesian join to ignore the null values.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.couponid, c.branchid, c.chainid
      FROM `users_roles` a, `field_data_field_ypefthinos` b,
      `custom_redemptions` c WHERE(a.uid = 1 AND b.field_ypefthinos_uid = a.uid AND b.entity_id = c.branchid);

you tray this query......
```

Comment: This one works, same with query 2 with unused tables joined but my full query needs all the tables

Comment: Please add a description to your answer to explain how it works.

Comment: required table name and fields to join table

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, the error was some tables on db2 are empty, but still they're not used. However I would like to know if there is a work-around for example:

```
SELECT a.uid FROM asdf a, asdf2 b
WHERE a.rid = 1
```

In this example only table a is used, so table b shouldn't affect the query if it empty but it does, is there a work-around?

Comment: You could rewrite the query to replace the cartesian join with a full outer join for each of them (actually you will use a left outer join with MySQL, since the other one is not available)

Answer (score 0):

When you say

```
select *
from
tbl1, tbl2
```

and you have no `WHERE` clause, you will have all combinations of those tables.
but when any of the table have `no data` in it, then you get `nothing`.

This means you may need to check `whether you have data in other tables` also.

**Demo**

with no data in `tbl2`

```
create table tbl1 (id1 int);
create table tbl2 (id2 int); 

insert into tbl1 select 1;
insert into tbl1 select 2;
insert into tbl1 select 3;

select * from tbl1, tbl2

OutPut:___
```

With data in `tbl1` and `tbl2`

```
insert into tbl2 select 10;
insert into tbl2 select 20;
insert into tbl2 select 30;

select * from tbl1, tbl2

OutPut:

ID1    ID2
  1     10 
  1     20 
  1     30 
  2     10 
  2     20 
  2     30 
  3     10 
  3     20 
  3     30
```

Comment: Then, how can I check if the table has data, if it has include in the query if not ignore it?

Comment: Why those tables are included in the query when nothing is selected from them?? may be because show result only when some data is present in those tables. If this is not the reason then you don't need these tables in the query...